# post back of Dropdownlist in web user control all other fields become empty

Tags: c#, asp.net, updatepanel

i have a aspx page in which i have placeholder inside the panel

as

```
<div>
    <div>
        <div>
            <div>
                <div>
                    <div>
                        <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="UpdatePanelLinks">
                            <ContentTemplate>
                                <center>
                                    <asp:Button Text="ADD" ID="btnAdd" runat="server" Width="100" OnClick="btnAdd_Click" />&nbsp;
                                    <asp:Button Text="Edit" ID="btnEdit" runat="server" Width="100" OnClick="btnEdit_Click" />&nbsp;
                                    <asp:Button Text="Delete" ID="btnDelete" runat="server" Width="100" OnClick="btnDelete_Click" /></center>
                                <asp:LinkButton ID="usercontroldata" runat="server" Text="Branches" 
                                    OnClick="usercontrol_Click"></asp:LinkButton>
                            </ContentTemplate>
                        </asp:UpdatePanel>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div >
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDepartments" runat="server" Text="Departments" OnClick="lnkDepartments_Click"></asp:LinkButton>
                </div>
                <div >
                </div>
                <div >
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkProjects" runat="server" Text="Projects" OnClick="lnkProjects_Click"></asp:LinkButton>
                </div>
                <div >
                </div>
                <div >
                    &nbsp;
                </div>                       
            </div>
            <div>
                <div>
                    <asp:Label Text="" Visible="false" ID="lblmessage" runat="server" />
                    <div>
                        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel" runat="server">
                            <Triggers>
                                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="lnkBranches" EventName="Click" />
                                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="lnkDepartments" />
                                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="lnkProjects" />
                                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnAdd" />
                                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnEdit" />
                                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnDelete" />
                            </Triggers>
                            <ContentTemplate>
                                <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="MainPanel">
                                    <div class="padding_branch">
                                        <asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder1" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
                                    </div>
                                </asp:Panel>
                            </ContentTemplate>
                        </asp:UpdatePanel>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel" runat="server">
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="lnkBranches" EventName="Click" />
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="lnkDepartments" />
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="lnkProjects" />
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnAdd" />
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnEdit" />
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnDelete" />
    </Triggers>
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="MainPanel">
            <div >
                <asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder1" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>                                     
            </div>
        </asp:Panel>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

and on the aspx.cs page i am dynamically add the web user control on click of links

and on the add button click the new user control is loaded

```
 protected void usercontrol_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
        if (ViewState["controlname"] != null)
        {
            PlaceHolder pl = MainPanel.FindControl(ViewState["controlname"].ToString()) as PlaceHolder;
            if (pl.Controls.Count > 0)
            {
                pl.Controls.RemoveAt(0);
            }
        }

        Control uc = (Control)Page.LoadControl("~/usercontrol_Data.ascx");

        ViewState["path"] = "~/usercontrol_Data.ascx";
        ViewState["controlname"] = "PlaceHolder1";
        ViewState["name"] = "usercontrol";
        PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(uc);
 }
```

i am also mainaining the web user control on Page_Load

```
        if (Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            if (ViewState["path"] != null)
            {
                Control uc1 = (Control)Page.LoadControl(ViewState["path"].ToString());

                PlaceHolder pl = MainPanel.FindControl(ViewState["controlname"].ToString()) as PlaceHolder;
                pl.Controls.Add(uc1);
            }
        }
```

and there is dropdown list on the form user control when iam selecting any of the option from the user control it post back and all the other fields become empty for textboxes etc . this happans for the first time and for next time all the fields retain there values

please help

thanks

Comment: For future posts, consider leaving the unnecessary code out of excerpts you post.  All of those divs in the first sample make it difficult to see what's going on, and have no effect on functionality.  **This is just a suggestion.**

Comment: thanks for suggestion i will keep it in mind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have done this by assigning the same ID to the control every time when the control loads dynamically. this is because when the control added dynamically every time it get the new ID that is creating the problem for me

uc1.ID="Web_User_Control_ID";

every time the control load asign this ID  to it will resole the problem

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `Page.IsPostBack` to `!Page.IsPostback` in your `Page_Load` event.

Answer (score 0):

Dynamically added controls are **not** persisted between post backs; you have to re-add your dynamically added controls on **each** post back.  On each page request, asp.net will parse your aspx file, build the html structure of your page, then fill in any previously filled-in values via ViewState and posted values, then serve it up.  That's it.  It will never automatically re-add dynamically added content.

So once you run this code

```
protected void usercontrol_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //...
    Control uc = (Control)Page.LoadControl("~/usercontrol_Data.ascx");

    ViewState["path"] = "~/usercontrol_Data.ascx";
    ViewState["controlname"] = "PlaceHolder1";
    ViewState["name"] = "usercontrol";
    PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(uc);
}
```

you need to somehow know to re-run it every time the user posts back

Comment: that the problem how can i rerun this code ,i am maintaining the state at page load as in my question. any suggestion?

Comment: Refactor the code above in to a new method; say LoadMyControl and call it in the usercontrol_click and Page_Load events.

Comment: @GurbaxSinghBhangal - Kev is right.  You need to put this control-adding code in one place and re-call on page load if needed